# NameError after Dill/Marshal deserialisation

Tags: python, dill

I am trying to dump a compiled piece of compiled Python code using either `marshal` or `dill`.

The source is compiled with `compiled(src, "<source>", "exec", optimize=2)`, the compiled code does run well.

However, when the compiled code is dumped with either `dill` or `marshal`, and loaded again,
the code raises `NameError` as in the example below.

Code example:

1. File `source.py`

   ```py
   import sympy
   pp = sympy.pprint
   x = sympy.Symbol("x")
   def p(*args):
      try:
         pp(*args)
      except TypeError:
         print(*args)
   p(5*x+1)
   ```
2. File `compiler.py`

   ```py
   import dill
   #import marshal

   with open("source.py") as fp:
      src = fp.read()
   compiled = compile(src, "<source>", "exec", optimize=2)
   exec(compiled)             # ok
   obj = dill.dumps(compiled)
   loaded = dill.loads(obj)
   exec(loaded)               # NameError: name "pp" is not defined
   ```

How can I fix this? And if it is intended behaviour, is there any alternatives to serialise/deserialise the compiled code? (I am not concerned about security yet.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, neither with `dill`, nor with `marshal`.